# BeginScope with Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I want to use the feature the `Microsoft.Logger` has at Serilog directly, the `BeginScope` feature.

I know that I can use Microsoft `ILogger` and setup Serilog to be the underlying logger but it's too much trouble at this point of the app.

I want to know if there is a `BeginScope` equivalent in Serilog.

The information at the internet is not straight forward, there are mentions that Serilog support that but nowhere is mentioned if it's directly supported or by using the Microsoft classes.

Comment: https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/

Comment: @DanielA.White So the answer is no? I have read that and I see that BeginScope exists in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, but my question is: Can i use something similar to that using only Serilog?

Comment: theres enrichers that you can use to define your own scopes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, Serilog has a native equivalent of this feature, called using `LogContext.PushProperty()`.

To enable this, you first must add `Enrich.FromLogContext()` to your Serilog `LoggerConfiguration`, for example:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext() // <- this line
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} " +
                                     "{Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

Then, to push properties onto the context (equivalent to `ILogger.BeginScope()`), use:

```cs
using (LogContext.PushProperty("OrderId", 1234))
{
    Log.Information("Processing a new order");
    // ...etc
}
```

The configuration above includes `{Properties:j}` to ensure all event properties, such as those from the log context, are included in the output. How you'll view the additional properties will depend upon which sink you're using.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I think they should mention that this is equivalent to `BeginScope` so this page can get the traffic from these keywords.

Comment: The source code for `LogContext` is refreshingly easy to read, I recommend taking a read. https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Context/LogContext.cs

Answer (score 8):

@Nicholas's answer is correct. I just wanted to drop a small worked example for anyone else coming to this thread to point out something that's not so obvious;

Here some example code that shows how to use Serilog context;

```cs
void Main()
{
    var log = Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    
    .CreateLogger();
    Log.Logger = log;
    log.Information("Starting app");
    
    Task.WaitAll(
        Task.Run (() => GetNums(10,15, 2, "evens")),
        Task.Run (() => GetNums(11, 15, 2, "odds"))
    );
    
    log.Information("Finished.");

    Console.ReadLine();
    
}

static Random R = new Random();

static void GetNums(int start, int cnt, int inc, string name)
{
    using(var log = LogContext.PushProperty("name", name))
    {
        for (int i = start; i < start + cnt; i+=inc)
        {
            Log.Information("{number},{name}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(R.Next(500));
        }
    }
}
```

produces this output

```
[17:11:31 INF] Starting app
[17:11:31 INF] 10,evens
[17:11:31 INF] 11,odds
[17:11:31 INF] 12,evens
[17:11:31 INF] 14,evens
[17:11:32 INF] 13,odds
[17:11:32 INF] 16,evens
[17:11:32 INF] 15,odds
[17:11:32 INF] 18,evens
[17:11:32 INF] 20,evens
[17:11:32 INF] 17,odds
[17:11:32 INF] 22,evens
[17:11:33 INF] 24,evens
[17:11:33 INF] 19,odds
[17:11:33 INF] 21,odds
[17:11:34 INF] 23,odds
[17:11:34 INF] 25,odds
[17:11:34 INF] Finished.
```

The thing I wanted to point out, is that the items logged to the context won't appear in the logs, (i.e. won't be logged) if the named value does not appear in your template.

For example, in the code above, if we change `Log.Information("{number},{name}",i);` to `Log.Information("{number}",i);` then this is what you would get, and this is similar to what you might get if you don't configure enrichment `Enrich.FromLogContext()`. It's subtle and easy to forget to update the template and chase your tail trying to find the bug.

without template string including the named properties included in the context

```
[17:22:11 INF] Starting app
[17:22:11 INF] 10
[17:22:11 INF] 11
[17:22:11 INF] 12
[17:22:11 INF] 13
[17:22:11 INF] 15
[17:22:11 INF] 17
[17:22:12 INF] 14
[17:22:12 INF] 16
[17:22:12 INF] 19
[17:22:12 INF] 18
[17:22:12 INF] 20
[17:22:12 INF] 21
[17:22:12 INF] 23
[17:22:12 INF] 22
[17:22:12 INF] 24
[17:22:13 INF] 25
[17:22:13 INF] Finished.
```

also, the enriched properties are `appended` to the end of the string, so
`Log.Information("{name},{number}", i);` would produce

```
[17:35:11 INF] Starting app
[17:35:11 INF] 11,{number}
[17:35:11 INF] 10,{number}
```

Happy logging! Hope this helped.

Comment: But the example code doesn't log the defined properties because a complete output template was not defined.  You are correct that the default output template does not include the "PushProperties", but Nicholas's example already includes `{Properties:j}` in the configured output template and even has an explanation at the end of his answer.  In other words, if an output template is properly defined during logging configuration, the properties WILL appear in the logs automatically without adding them explicitly to every logging call.

Comment: txs @CPerkins - I wasn't contradicting Nicholas; just offering some code that people can run and expand on the topic with an example that is easy to run, and shows the difference of including the properties in the template and not including it.